# Can someone please nuke the comments on my answer to this question?

Tags: support, status-completed

Q: [Will not disclosing that I worked as a contractor not an employee count against me in a hiring decision?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/will-not-disclosing-that-i-worked-as-a-contractor-not-an-employee-count-against)

The OP is very anxious and we've ended up with a cyclical and not very useful conversation in the comments. Can it be removed? Thanks.

Edit to add: not the first comment! That one is useful...

Answer (score 5):

I've removed the comment thread.

In the future, you can use a custom flag on the post to make this kind of request.  Only moderators (and the posters of the comments) can remove comments, so while a post on meta reaches more people it doesn't, in this case, reach more people who can fulfill the request.

Below each post you should have a 'flag' option if you have over [15 reputation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/):

[image: Flag location under every post]

> [image: Flag Dialogue]

You can also flag comments directly (but if there are multiple comments you want to have removed, it is often quicker and easier for everyone if you flag one comment and ask to have all related comments removed as well).

(You're welcome to post on meta if you prefer; just pointing out an alternative.)

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)